# Filtering Messages to all Applications in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mouse, sendmessage

Most modern mice have a feature called “debounce” that prevents them from clicking more than once when the buttons bounce. My mouse unfortunately does not which leads it to send two or more clicks when I only want to send one. I want to prevent this from happening using C++.

I have two ideas for how to do this. One is by installing a low level mouse hook to block clicks that occur in too quick succession, and the other is by filtering the messages sent to applications in the same way.

However, I don’t know how to do either of these things, or if they are even possible. I tried searching for the solution but I couldn’t find anything.

I found instructions on how to install a low level mouse hook, the issue is the details and the filtering of clicks. If anyone could tell me which of my two ideas are possible, which one is better, or if there is another way that will work, that would be great.

Edit: I’ve since found out that PeekMessage has exactly the functionality that I am looking for, but only for windows from the current thread, whereas I need to remove messages from all windows. Based on this, I assume my only option is the hook.

Comment: I assume this on Windows, based on your other tags.  If not, please edit the tags.

Comment: It is, looks like it was changed already though. Thank you.